# CentOS Kickstart File

Tags: centos, kickstart

I am trying to install CentOS in VirtualBox via kickstart files. I have downloaded the CentOS Minimal installation (1708) and created a virtual machine with it.

I am using the anaconda-ks.cfg file as the default kickstart file for it.

With the base CentOS iso, I have extracted it via 7z, placed my kickstart file in DirName as DirName/anaconda-ks.cfg. I then made an iso for it.

```
7z x CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708.iso -oDirName
sudo genisoimage -joliet-long -o NameForISO.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -v -T -V 'CentOS 7 x86_64' DirName
```

Note: In isolinux.cfg I added the lines (as in http://ideanist.com/2017/03/09/unattended-kickstart-installation-centos-7/):

```
label is
  menu label ^Kickstart
  menu default
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 inst.ks=cdrom:/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet
```

Errors: Upon attaching the iso to my virtual machine, and selecting the kickstart option, I see 3: [!] Installation source (Error setting up software source). if I do not have any network information included in my anaconda-ks.cfg file. If I include the lines:

```
network  --bootproto=static --device=eth0 --gateway=1.1.1.1 --ip=2.2.2.2 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --ipv6=auto --activate
network  --bootproto=static --device=eth1 --gateway=3.3.3.3 --ip=4.4.4.4 --netmask=255.255.255.128 --ipv6=auto --activate
```

I get `Starting automated install.....`, and the `.` trail on forever, never installing using my kickstart file.

How do I get rid of these errors? Am I not specifying something properly?